# With gcc -O3 optimization, why does the loop index's type affect gcc's internal GIMPLE vector constants (but not the final asm)?

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, compiler-optimization, auto-vectorization, gimple

I created a struct array, and here is my source code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 256


typedef struct arc {
   int num;
} arc_t;

typedef double cost_t;

typedef struct  basket {
    arc_t *a;
    cost_t cost;

} BASKET;

static BASKET basket[N];
static BASKET *perm[N];

int main() {
     __asm__ ("########");
     int j;
   
    for ( j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
    
        perm[j] = &(basket[j]) ;
    }
    __asm__ ("########");
    
    printf("%d\n",perm[1]->a->num);

    return 0;
}
```

At this point, I have defined an integer variable "j." When using the command `gcc -O3 p.c -fdump-tree-vect-details -fopt-info-vec -S -mavx2` to print intermediate files, in the generated intermediate file at the location of my marker (asm ("########");), there is the following content:

```
<bb 2> [local count: 10737416]:
  __asm__ __volatile__("########");
  vect_cst__13 = { 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8 };
  vect_cst__22 = { 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16 };
  _27 = (long unsigned int) &basket;
  vect_cst__28 = {_27, _27, _27, _27};
```

However, when I define "long j," it results in the following intermediate file:

```
  <bb 2> [local count: 10737416]:
  __asm__ __volatile__("########");
  vect_cst__14 = { 4, 4, 4, 4 };
  vect_cst__19 = { 16, 16, 16, 16 };
  _23 = (long unsigned int) &basket;
  vect_cst__24 = {_23, _23, _23, _23};
```

This is a part of the difference, but what confuses me the most is that, with Peter Cordes's assistance, we speculated that the difference in the intermediate code might be due to the distinct sizes of int and long data types.
But `j` is just an array index, so why would its data type have this impact? I've printed the first four addresses of "basket[j]" in both cases of `int j` and `long j`, and they are the same.  The gcc version is 10.3.0

Since there are differences in the intermediate files at this point, I suspect that different optimizations might have been applied by the front-end compiler. Where should I look for information related to this? How does GCC analyze struct arrays?

Comment: If you did anything with the loop counter other than index contiguous elements, you might get some final asm code-gen that actually used vectors of `j` values (and incremented each element by 4 or 8).  Unlike in this case, where these are (almost certainly) just temporaries invented during auto-vectorization and optimized away again before generating asm.  Of course `&basket[j]` isn't going to change.  You should try `arr[j] = j;` or `sum += j;`, although in both those cases I expect GCC to narrow the loop counter to match the size its used with.

Comment: @PeterCordes I want to understand why these temporary artifacts are different, but I've been unable to pinpoint which part of the process generates them.

Comment: My mental model of what's going on is that GCC invents a 32-byte vector filled with `j` values as part of an early step in figuring out what it has to work with and what it might use if it needs it.  But it ends up *not* needing it at all, so it's no present in the asm anywhere, and not with a different width.  With a 4-byte vs. 8-byte `j`, unrolling the original loop enough to fill one SIMD vector with `j` values produces either 4 or 8 of them, requiring an increment by 4 or 8.

Comment: @PeterCordes It will eventually be used after some address additions and assigned to the "perm" array.

Comment: Oh right, you are doing something pretty close to `arr[j] = j`, just with pointers.  `&basket[j]` is just `basket + j`.  With narrow `int j`, implicit conversion to pointer width still happens.  (Or for 32-bit code, an `int64_t j` loop counter would get narrowed to 32-bit I expect).  I don't know why GCC doesn't "notice" this before inventing a vector of 8x `j` values, if my guess is right about what that vector constant is for.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you, I'm going to analyze what the compiler's frontend is doing and investigate why the type of the array index variable has such an impac